# When training a model over multiple GPUs on the same machine using Pytorch, how is the batch size divided?

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation, multi-gpu

Even looking through Pytorch forums I'm still not certain about this one. Let's say I'm using Pytorch DDP to train a model over `4` GPUs **on the same machine**.

Suppose I choose a batch size of `8`. Is the model theoretically backpropagating over `2` examples every step and the final results we see are for a model trained with a batch size of `2`, or does the model gather the gradients together at every step to get the result from each GPU and backpropagate with a batch size of `8`?

Answer (score 0):

The actual batch size is the size of input you feed to each worker, in your case is 8. In other words, the BP runs every 8 examples.

A concrete code example: https://gist.github.com/sgraaf/5b0caa3a320f28c27c12b5efeb35aa4c#file-ddp_example-py-L63. This is the batch size.